# Get values from xml with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath, xml-parsing

In the image there is a simple querie but not peform as I wish.
all values of one cateogry is wrapped by  {,} and I need one value per line without these characters

[image: sql_result]

Here is a sample of xml column

```xml
<GPCodedValueDomain2 xsi:type='typens:GPCodedValueDomain2' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:typens='http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.6'>
<DomainName>tBooleanDomain</DomainName><FieldType>esriFieldTypeSmallInteger</FieldType>
<MergePolicy>esriMPTDefaultValue</MergePolicy><SplitPolicy>esriSPTDuplicate</SplitPolicy>
<Description>A 0/1 boolean domain</Description><Owner>sde</Owner>
<CodedValues xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfCodedValue'><CodedValue xsi:type='typens:CodedValue'>
<Name>Falso</Name>
<Code xsi:type='xs:short'>0</Code>
</CodedValue><CodedValue xsi:type='typens:CodedValue'>
<Name>Verdadeiro</Name>
<Code xsi:type='xs:short'>1</Code></CodedValue></CodedValues></GPCodedValueDomain2>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following way, you can get a single value per line without any other characters

```
unnest(xpath('//Name/text()', definition)) as "value"
```

[image]